# Find first element in RDD satisfying the given predicate

Tags: apache-spark

How to find the first element in a normal RDD( Because in PairRDD, we can use lookup(key) API ) which satisfy a predicate? And after finding the first element, it should exit the RDD traversal. 
Looking for a solution without using legacy for loops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
rdd.filter(p).top(1)
```

or if you don't have an order on the RDD

```
rdd.filter(p).take(1)
```

Comment: nice way. But still the filter traverses the entire RDD. Correct? How could we eliminate it?

Comment: No, all the transformations are lazy, so it will stop traversing when there are no more elements requested.

Comment: Great. so the filter transformation will stop when it finds the first element satisfying the predicate. And that value will given to the driver. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. However in a clustered setup the first element found might not be the first element of your original RDD.

Comment: Got it. First element will be from the executor for which the RDD partition satisfied the condition first. Thanks for quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions stated are perfectly correct. Here is another method to achieve the same goal

```
rdd.filter(p).first
```